# Ionic Angular Query string parse to login

Tags: php, angular, ionic3

```
  logindata:any ={};

  constructor(
    public navCtrl:NavController,
    public http:Http
  ) {
    this.logindata.username="";
    this.logindata.password="";

    let url:string = "http://demo.in/app/userdetails.php?userid=""&password=""";
    let dataPost =JSON.stringify ({
        userid:this.logindata.username,
        password:this.logindata.password
    });

    this.http.post(url,dataPost)
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data);
    })

  }
```

This ionic angular when i am parse user input in userid and password it error. details enter in input its shows error it is way or not i not sure for that because i beginner

Comment: http://demo.in/app/userdetails.php?userid='+this.logindata.username+'&password='+this.logindata.password

Comment: And remove the dataPost and in the http post put {} instead of dataPost, but be sure you request in this way is wrong since you are posting a username and password to achieve $_GET the username and password and want to send them as $_POST and the whole proccess is confusing , since you either send dataPost as post request or put them directly in the url string and send get request without dataPost.

Answer (score 0):

Passing username and password as url parameter is not recommended

For post url `http://demo.in/app/userdetails.php`. Use the below code

```
let url:string = "http://demo.in/app/userdetails.php";
let dataPost =JSON.stringify ({
    userid:this.logindata.username,
    password:this.logindata.password
});
this.http.post(url,dataPost)
    .map(res=>res.json())
    .subscribe(data =>{
        console.log(data);
    })
```

[see more...](https://serverfault.com/a/371918)

Comment: but i want to perse userid and password in string

Comment: you can parse them to string by using: '' + this.logindata.username